# Pseudocode Help - File Handling

Tags: python, pseudocode

I was stuck at the following bit of pseudocode, more specifically with the question: How many fields are there in each record?, and what `pupilArray(index)` means.

```
pupilFile = “studentFile.txt”
OPEN pupilFile in “WRITE” mode
FOR index = 1 to len(pupilArray)
  WRITELINE(pupilfile, pupilArray(index))
ENDFOR
CLOSE pupilFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not completely sure what this is asking... but let's break it down

```
pupilFile = “studentFile.txt” OPEN pupilFile in “WRITE” mode
```

This would indicate that you're opening up the file in write mode

FOR index = 1 to len(pupilArray) 
       WRITELINE(pupilfile, pupilArray(index)) 
   ENDFOR

`pupilArray(index)` appears to be accesing the `index`-th field of the array `pupilArray`.  ie, `pupilArray(0)` is the first element. `pupilArray(1)` is the second.  And so on.

The "number of fields" *could* be the number of elements in this array.  Or it could be the number of fields in the array elements (assuming they are objects).

Like if 
`pupilArray(0)` was the object `{ A:"A", B:"B" }` then you could say there are 2 fields.  But as worded the answer is unclear to me

And close the file
   CLOSE pupilFile

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time with programming then please go through some good documentation or articles / books about data structure.

A small premier is this - any array (usually) can be viewed a continuous block of memory assigned to a variable declared as an array. What I mean is

```
// If you declare 
a = array(5)
// Then a = [block0|block1|block2|block3|block4]
```

notice that that the `index` starts with 0 (generally again) and not 1. This is usually the convention.

Now once an array is declared, you can iterate over it. using a for loop. Just as in your problem.

```
for i = 0 and i < length(a)
    print a[i]
    i = i  + 1
```

This will (in an imaginary language) go over each `index` of the array, access the memory assigned to it, retrieve the value stored there and finally print them.

Armed with this knowledge, look at your problem and, what do you see?

1.> Opening a file in `write` mode

2.> Going over each element of the array

3.> Writing them to the file.

Imagining your array looks like this - [1,2,4,6,2,7,6,10]

The final file you obtain will be something like this -

```
1
2
4
6
2
7
6
10
```

Given the fact that your `writeline` function actually adds a newline after writing the line.

Does this help you?